# Delaying methods in C#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, timer, delay

I have the next 2 methods:

```
public void RunDFS(UpgradedPictureBox[,] i_PictureBoxes)
        {
            foreach (AdjacencyList list in m_StartOfVectorList) // Reset all colors to white. Not sure this is necessary.
            {
                foreach(AdjacencyNode node in list.m_AdjacencyNodes)
                {
                    i_PictureBoxes[node.m_StartVertex, node.m_EndVertex].BackColor = Color.White;
                }
            }


            foreach (AdjacencyList list in m_StartOfVectorList)
            {
                if(list.m_AdjacencyNodes.Count > 0 && i_PictureBoxes[list.m_AdjacencyNodes[0].m_StartVertex, list.m_AdjacencyNodes[0].m_EndVertex]
                       .BackColor == Color.White)
                {
                    Visit(list.m_AdjacencyNodes[0], i_PictureBoxes);
                }
            }
        }

        public async void Visit(AdjacencyNode i_Vertex, UpgradedPictureBox[,] i_PictureBoxes)
        {

            i_PictureBoxes[i_Vertex.m_StartVertex, i_Vertex.m_EndVertex].BackColor = Color.Gray;
            AdjacencyList vertexNeighbors = m_StartOfVectorList[i_Vertex.m_EndVertex];
            foreach(AdjacencyNode node in vertexNeighbors.m_AdjacencyNodes)
            {
                if (i_PictureBoxes[node.m_StartVertex, node.m_EndVertex].BackColor == Color.White)
                {
                    Visit(node, i_PictureBoxes);
                }
            }
            await TaskEx.Delay(300);
            i_PictureBoxes[i_Vertex.m_StartVertex, i_Vertex.m_EndVertex].BackColor = Color.Black;
        }
```

Let's say RunDFS is being called once. And as we can see, Visit is being called multiple times.
In Visit method, we are coloring a button to a different color.
I want to delay the program once the color is being changed. I want the color to be changed, and then, a few miliseconds later, it would let the program continue running.
I've been trying to use Sleep but I've understood it's disabled in C# 4.0.
Also, await Delay is not working for C# 4.0, but for later versions.
I tried to use the Timer class, but in order to paint a picturebox, I need to pass more parameters to the EventHandler, something I wasn't able to do.
Can anyone please assist me where I should write that Timer method?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try Thread.Sleep(1000);

Comment: @Eugene Sleep Unfortunately, is disabled in Windows Form

Comment: since the c# 4 is really old... try the following if one could work: ```System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer```, ```System.Windows.Forms.Timer```, ```System.Timers.Timer```

Comment: @Lei I tried using timer events, but couldn't get it to work with my program. I just want the i_PictureBox[..,..].BackColor = White to be delayed, so I can see the change happening in front of my eyes. Why doesn't await delay work with the new edited code?

Comment: @ZvikaCohen  you set backcolor to black after the delay, not white. and maybe the delay time 300ms too short and so you cant feel it maybe? and since your Visit method is not awaited, all elements are set at same time.